# Stata: replace, if, forvalues

Tags: loops, if-statement, stata

```
use "locationdata.dta", clear
gen ring=.
* Philly City Hall
gen lat_center = 39.9525468
gen lon_center = -75.1638855
destring(INTPTLAT10), replace
destring(INTPTLON10), replace
vincenty INTPTLAT10 INTPTLON10 lat_center lon_center , hav(distance_km) inkm
quietly su distance_km
local min = r(min)
replace ring=0 if (`min' <= distance_km < 1)
local max = ceil(r(max))
* forval loop does not work
forval i=1/`max'{
    local j = `i'+1
    replace ring=`i' if (`i' <= distance_km < `j')
}
```

I am drawing rings by 1 km from a point. The last part of the code (`forval`) does not work. Something wrong here?

**EDIT:**

The result for the `forval` part is as follows:

```
. forval i=1/`max'{
2.         local j = `i'+1
3.         replace ring=`i' if `i' <= distance_km < `j'
4. }
(1746 real changes made)
(0 real changes made)
(0 real changes made)
(0 real changes made)
....
```

So, replacing does not work for `i = 2` and beyond.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I added the result to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double inequality such as

```
(`min' <= distance_km < 1)
```

which makes sense according to mathematical conventions is clearly legal in Stata. Otherwise, your code would have triggered a syntax error. However, Stata does not hold evaluation until the entire expression is evaluated. The parentheses here are immaterial, as what is key is how their contents are evaluated. As it turns out, the result is unlikely to be what you want.

In more detail: Stata interprets this expression from left to right as follows. The first equality

```
`min' <= distance_km
```

is true or false and thus evaluated as 0 or 1. Evidently you want to select values such that

```
distance_km >= `min'
```

and for such values the inequality above is true and returns 1. Stata would then take a result of 1 forward and turn to the second inequality, evaluating

```
1 < 1
```

(i.e. result of first inequality `< 1`), but that is false for such values. Conversely,

```
(`min' <= distance_km < 1)
```

will be evaluated as

```
 0 < 1
```

-- which is true (returns 1) -- if and only if

```
 `min' > distance_km
```

In short, what you intend would need to be expressed differently, namely by

```
  (`min' <= distance_km) & (distance_km < 1)
```

I conjecture that this is at the root of your problem.

Note that Stata has an `inrange()` function but it is not quite what you want here.

But, all that said, from looking at your code the inequalities and your loop both appear quite unnecessary. You want your rings to be 1 km intervals, so that

```
 gen ring = floor(distance_km)
```

can replace the entire block of code after your call to `vincenty`, as `floor()` rounds down with integer result. You appear to know of its twin `ceil()`.

Some other small points, incidental but worth noting:

1. You can `destring` several variables at once.
2. Putting constants in variables with `generate` is inefficient. Use `scalar`s for this purpose. (However, if `vincenty` requires variables as input, that would override this point, but it points up that `vincenty` is too strict.)
3. `summarize, meanonly` is better for calculating just the minimum and maximum. The option name is admittedly misleading here. See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0135 for discussion.

As a matter of general Stata practice, your post should explain where the user-written `vincenty` comes from, although it seems that is quite irrelevant in this instance.

For completeness, here is a rewrite, although you need to test it against your data.

```
 use "locationdata.dta", clear
 * Philly City Hall
 scalar lat_center = 39.9525468
 scalar lon_center = -75.1638855
 destring INTPTLAT10 INTPTLON10, replace
 vincenty INTPTLAT10 INTPTLON10 lat_center lon_center , hav(distance_km) inkm
 gen ring = floor(distance_km)
```